# Printing out specific information in a large text file

Tags: python

I want to read in and parse a large text file (over 900,000) lines but I only want to output a specific set of lines throughout the file. I have key words & numbers I'm looking for but to simplify the questions, I'm only looking for these specific words..'Lot ID', 'Wafer ID', 'Chip X Coord', and 'Chip Y Coord'.

I have a string containing everything I need. I'm just not sure how to compare to a large text file. I tried if statements but I'm not sure what to do next. Once again I'm a beginner.

```
my_list = ['Lot ID', 'Wafer ID', 'Chip X Coord', 'Chip Y Coord']
array = []
correct = False 

with open("HP.txt", "r") as lines:

for line in lines:
   line = line.strip('\n') 
   line = line.strip('\t')  
   line = line.strip() 
   line = line.replace(" ", "") 
   array.append(line)   

if 'Lot ID' in line:
   correct = True  

if 'Wafer ID' in line:
   correct = True

if 'Chip X Coord' in line:
   correct = True 

if 'Chip Y Coord' in line:
   correct = True 

   print(array)


f.close()
```

I want to output a list of these specific words every time they show up in the file.

Comment: Please [edit] and indent your code properly. It's invalid currently. Also `f` is not defined.

Comment: You need to make a [mcve], including the contents of the input file (not the whole thing - just an example snippet) and your expected output.

Comment: You're removing all spaces with the line `line.replace(" ", "") ` then trying to find a string with a space in the line `Lot ID`

Comment: There are definitely better ways to do this, but you're removing all the spaces with line.replace(" ", ""), so none of your conditions will ever match.  Once you get rid of that, you probably only want to add the line to your array if the condition matches (assuming array is what you actually want to output).

Comment: One more reason this code snippet will not run is the fact that you are closing a file that is set under the variable `f` (i.e. `f.close()`) where in fact you have opened your file as `lines`. So it should be `lines.close()` at the end. This is an addition to the other comments.

Comment: @Bajro No, `lines` will be closed automatically thanks to the with-statement.

Comment: Besides the code issues, what is your goal? Just to check if any of the strings in the array occurs in the text file, what is the purpose of the `correct` boolean, and what do you mean by "I only want to output a specific set of lines throughout the file"

Comment: @wjandrea That is correct but Python will not be happy with this line of code and hence will not execute the code at all. So, we won't even reach closing the file automatically as the code won't run.

Comment: @Bajro No, the code will execute up to the line with `f`, when it will raise a NameError.

Comment: @wjandrea No, as Python is first compiled to bytecode and then interpreted, this code is never going to be executed up to the line with `f.close()` as the error is thrown during the compilation stage.

Comment: @Bajro NameErrors occur at run-time, not compile-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed you wanted to write the matching lines to an output file that I've creatively named output_lines.txt.

Note the list comprehension to determine if your line from the file contains any of the keywords.

```
[item for item in my_list if(item in line)]
```

This iterates through the values in your list of keywords and checks to see if the line of text contains that keyword. This way, you can add/remove keywords in your list without changing your code.

I also removed the line that removes spaces as all of your keywords have spaces.

This will go through and just print lines that contain your keywords

```
my_list = ['Lot ID', 'Wafer ID', 'Chip X Coord', 'Chip Y Coord']

with open("HP.txt", "r") as lines:
    with open("output_lines.txt","w+") as out_file:
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip('\n') 
            line = line.strip('\t')  
            line = line.strip() 
            is_in_list = any(item for item in my_list if(item in line)) 

            if is_in_list:
                print(line)
                out_file.write(line)
                out_file.write('\n')
```

This will extract and print based on context. It makes some strong assumptions about the input file.
- Every four lines will contain the four items you are looking for 
- All four items will be accounted for in each chunk

My test input looks like:

```
Lot ID=Q19176
Wafer ID=564
Chip X Coord=84834
Chip Y Coord=64738
Lot ID=Q19176
Wafer ID=987
Chip X Coord=3565
Chip Y Coord=35635
Lot ID=Q19176
Wafer ID=2343
Chip X Coord=2344
Chip Y Coord=6565
```

The code below gives the output:

```
Q19176_564_84834_64738
Q19176_987_3565_35635
Q19176_2343_2344_6565
```

It is filling a list with the values of the different items, which are location dependent - meaning Lot ID is always position 0, Wafer ID is always position 1...

```
with open("HP.txt", "r") as lines:
    with open("output_lines_context.txt","w+") as out_file:
        data_list = [None for i in range(4)]
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip('\n') 
            line = line.strip('\t')  
            line = line.strip() 
            items = line.split('=')
            if len(items) > 1:
                if 'Lot ID' in line:
                    data_list[0] = items[1]
                elif 'Wafer ID' in line:
                    data_list[1] = items[1]
                elif 'Chip X Coord' in line:
                    data_list[2] = items[1]
                elif 'Chip Y Coord' in line:
                    data_list[3] = items[1]
            has_none = any(i is None for i in data_list)
            if not has_none:
                print('_'.join(data_list))
                out_file.write('_'.join(data_list))
                out_file.write('\n')
                data_list = [None for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: Perhaps use `any([item for item in my_list if(item in line)])` so that the variable `is_in_array` makes more sense as a boolean

Comment: thanks @Alessi, I like that better. I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: `any(item in line for item in my_list)` is simpler

Comment: You need to supply some example input lines and desired output in your question. it sounds like you need to collect 4 rows at a time, then output a combination, but I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: This is great! What is the data_list = [None for i in range(4)]  do

Comment: That just initializes an empty list. I need a list exactly 4 elements long because I need to place the items in specific locations. It is not enough to append to the list. This way, it doesn't actually matter what order the items come in the file, they will always be correctly ordered in the output. If this works for you, could you mark is as the accepted answer.

Comment: yes, what exactly is the if not has_none function doing

Comment: that is checking to see if the list has all of its values. If none of the list values are None (pythons null), then the list has all 4 values and should output them. If any of the values has None, then it does not yet have all of the values and should not output them yet. Once it outputs the items, it re-initializes the list to an empty list and starts over.